# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException , Unexpected exception parsing XML document

Tags: spring

When executing a spring program,the below exception is thrown:

```
Sep 09, 2015 9:16:00 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1099f62: startup date [Wed Sep 09 21:16:00 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Sep 09, 2015 9:16:00 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/TargetSource
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:414)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at
.... 


org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
            at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
                at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
                at Application.main(Application.java:11)
            Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/TargetSource
                at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.registerAnnotationConfigProcessors(AnnotationConfigUtils.java:140)
                at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AnnotationConfigBeanDefinitionParser.java:47)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:174)
            ... 14 more
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.springframework.aop.TargetSource
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 24 more
```

The spring configuration is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test"/>
</beans>
```

I am unable to know how to resolve this issue. Please let me know any jar needs to be added to resolve this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why/How am I getting the error: NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/framework/ProxyFactory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021298/why-how-am-i-getting-the-error-noclassdeffounderror-org-springframework-aop-fr)

Comment: I was able resolve the issue when i add the spring-aop-2.5.6.jar in the Referenced Libraries.

Thanks for the possible solution!!It helped:)

Comment: "I was able resolve the issue when i add the spring-aop-2.5.6.jar in the Referenced Libraries."    Your words solved my problem, thank you very much

Comment: @tiankonghewo: Please upvote my above comment if it has helped you. It would be useful to others as well, who are facing the same/similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/TargetSource
```

can't you see this error message?

you need org.springframework.aop package

add your spring-aop-x.x.x.jar to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

@Horizon_Net, I was also able to resolve the issue by adding spring-aop-4.3.3.jar to my spring library folder. Thanks @keshav-pradeep-ramanath!

Comment: Please upvote my above comment if it has helped you. It would be useful to others as well, who are facing the same/similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was shading my self-contained jar to save space, and after upgrading to spring-context 4.3.4 (spring-context is dependent of spring-aop) from 3.2.6, I started having this problem. So what I had to do was to add it as a include-filter configuration in my maven-shade-plugin.